# Flink native kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I have some limitations with the rights required by Flink native deployment.

The prerequisites say

`KubeConfig, which has access to list, create, delete pods and **services**, configurable`

Specifically, my issue is I cannot have a service account with the rights to create/remove services. create/remove pods is not an issue. but services by policy only can be created within an internal tool.

could it be any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Flink creates two service in native Kubernetes integration.

- Internal service, which is used for internal communication between JobManager and TaskManager. It is only created when the HA is not enabled. Since the HA service will be used for the leader retrieval when HA enabled.
- Rest service, which is used for accessing the webUI or rest endpoint. If you have other ways to expose the rest endpoint, or you are using the application mode, then it is also optional. However, it is always be created currently. I think you need to change some codes to work around.